# Win Event Logs: Undocumented UAC value

Tags: powershell

I was looking through some logs and I found a modification to an AD machine account. The event ID is `4742`. The event name is `a computer account was changed.`.

In the log, it shows the changed/modified attributes, in this case it shows the changes are to the UAC values:

```
Changed Attributes:

    SAM Account Name:   -

    Display Name:       -

    User Principal Name:    -

    Home Directory:     -

    Home Drive:     -

    Script Path:        -

    Profile Path:       -

    User Workstations:  -

    Password Last Set:  -

    Account Expires:        -

    Primary Group ID:   -

    AllowedToDelegateTo:    -

    Old UAC Value:      0x80

    New UAC Value:      0x81

    User Account Control:   

        Account Disabled

    User Parameters:    -

    SID History:        -

    Logon Hours:        -

    DNS Host Name:      -

    Service Principal Names:    -
```

As shown, it changes the `Old_UAC` value to `0x81` . The problem is, in the [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/ne-iads-ads_user_flag_enum), only 0x80 is defined:

```
ADS_UF_ENCRYPTED_TEXT_PASSWORD_ALLOWED
Value: 0x80
The user can send an encrypted password.
```

I cannot find any reference to `0x81`. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserAccountControl is a bitflags attribute.

0x81 includes both:

ADS_UF_SCRIPT
ADS_UF_ENCRYPTED_TEXT_PASSWORD_ALLOWED